# Utilização Firebase em projeto SPA

Tags: angular, firebase

Preciso de uma ajuda com relação a boas praticas na utilização do *Firebase* em um projeto *SPA*, no meu caso o *Angular*.

Estou fazendo um curso de desenvolvimento com *Angular 4* e no tópico referente a utilização do Firebase como back-end da aplicação é feita a implementação da autenticação no console do *Angular*.
No curso é utilizada a opção "Adicionar o Firebase ao seu aplicativo da Web", que gera o codigo abaixo.

```
  var config = {
    apiKey: "<api key>",
    authDomain: "<authDomain>",
    databaseURL: "<databaseURL>",
    projectId: "<projectId>",
    storageBucket: "<storegeBucket>",
    messagingSenderId: "<messagingSenderId>"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Como a aplicação é *SPA* esses dados vão para o client. Não existe risco de alguém capturar os dados para desenvolver uma pagina fake e utilizar os recursos indevidamente?
Como faço para utilizar o Firebase em um projeto *SPA*?
É seguro utilizar a conexão direta do client com o *Firebase* ou preciso desenvolver um middleware para intermediar essa comunição?

Comment: Só vc não colocar esses dados no github em um repositório público por exemplo. Pelo angular ser compilado os arquivos gerados por ele já vem configurado com as chaves certa sem necessidade

Comment: Eduardo. A compilação gerada pelo Angular não é totalmente segura. Basta fazer uma analise mais "maldosa" no codigo gerado pelo build que conseguimos extrair as informações chapadas in code.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia amigo, o firebase tem essa "abertura" mesmo, o que vc precisa fazer é proteger internamente os dados, o database, o firestore e o storage, têm segurança atrelada ao usuário logado, então mesmo com acesso a esses dados o invasor nada pode fazer, outra forma de proteção adicional é travar no firebase o cors pra só aceitar conexões do seu servidor, no console tem opção de domínios permitidos, na parte de autenticação, e vc consegue manipular o cors tbm pelo gsutil .

Atenção ao Deixar o localhost liberado na autenticação, pois permite um estranho com esses dados de acesso criar um usuário, então a segurança tem que ser por todos os lados, tente deixar os dados acessíveis para os usuários individualmente, assim cada usuário tem acesso apenas aos dados relativos a ele, e os dados mais sensíveis vc pode deixar travado é só manipular através de functions.

Espero ter ajudado

Seguem alguns links

https://youtu.be/rtoxRg-kbt0

https://youtu.be/b7PUm7LmAOw

https://youtu.be/qLrDWBKTUZo

https://youtu.be/oFlHzF5U-HA

https://youtu.be/eW5MdE3ZcAw

Comment: Obrigado cara. Vou dar uma olhada.